# Unable to filter Directory.Getfiles by Certain string keywords

Tags: c#, methods

I'm trying to list out a file with .TXT extension and also only show file containing "EUROPE_" into a listbox

```
private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\temp\\FOLDER", "*.*", 
        SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Where(s =>  s.Contains("*EUROPE*") || s.EndsWith(".TXT"));
}
```

Nothing displayed when I click the button

Comment: First of all you'll need to use && instead of || since you want an AND not an OR. Also currently the only thing you're doing is retrieving the list, not displaying it at all.

Comment: You can't use wildcards in `Contains()`. That looks for the literal string containing "EUROPE" bookended by asterisks. You should just be using "EUROPE" without the wildcards.

Comment: What I don't understand is why you're using "\*.\*" for the search pattern when you could just specify "\*EUROPE\*.TXT" as the search pattern forget the whole `Where()` business.

Comment: @itsme86 are you sure that's supported? I'm not sure that's why I didn't include it in my answer.

Comment: @Joelius Yup, I'm sure. Just tested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to some adjustments in your code but it's not a bad start.
First of all you can just use the built in wildcard to only get txt-files. Then you can use the `Where` to determine which file contains "europe". After that you'll need to add each file to the listbox. Otherwise you obviously won't see them.

```
private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\temp\\FOLDER", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(s => s.ToUpper().Contains("EUROPE"));

    foreach(string file in files){
        listBox1.Items.Add(file);
    }
}
```

Edit:
You can indeed use the wildcard also to check if it contains europe. In my opinion it's also cleaner and more readable so use this (you'll still need the rest of the code other than this line of course). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56433853/10883465) which shows this exact method just without the code around it.

Comment: yup, its been a while .. now starting learn from scratch :)  .. anyway, this is works , correction from Rick also works ..

Answer (score 1):

You don’t have to use the where clause.
The following line of code should work:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\temp\\FOLDER", "*EUROPE_*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```